# High API usage, repeated calls!

Tags: apex, trigger, api, workflow, debug-logs

Over the weekend our Salesforce environment is now getting thousands of API calls every hour.

We have custom integrations that have not changed, nor have any API's been deprecated, or any server updates. We're simply at a loss, Salesforce support won't even help. The managed package has not been updated for 2 months and we have spoke to their senior support and they've confirmed it's not them.

Our Setup Audit trail doesn't identify any changes that would be linked to this.

We have setup our API integration to one specific user for debugging 'Chi' and you can see getting thousands of these same calls, can anyone tell us what it's trying to do?

Any help would be much appreciated!

```
42.0 APEX_CODE,DEBUG;APEX_PROFILING,FINEST;CALLOUT,INFO;DB,INFO;NBA,INFO;SYSTEM,DEBUG;VALIDATION,INFO;VISUALFORCE,INFO;WAVE,INFO;WORKFLOW,INFO
11:47:40.8 (8921497)|SOQL_EXECUTE_BEGIN|[12]|Aggregations:0|SELECT pba__Key__c, pba__Value__c FROM pba__Setting__c LIMIT 10000
11:47:40.8 (14484309)|SOQL_EXECUTE_END|[12]|Rows:27
11:47:40.8 (27287877)|SOQL_EXECUTE_BEGIN|[12]|Aggregations:0|SELECT Id, DeveloperName, Name, NamespacePrefix, SObjectType FROM RecordType
11:47:40.8 (49076707)|SOQL_EXECUTE_END|[12]|Rows:21
11:47:40.8 (353239942)|SOQL_EXECUTE_BEGIN|[12]|Aggregations:0|SELECT RecordTypeId, pba__SystemAccountContact__c, pba__SystemIsIndividual__c, OwnerId FROM Account WHERE (Id IN (null)) LIMIT 10001
11:47:40.8 (356752516)|SOQL_EXECUTE_END|[12]|Rows:0
11:47:40.8 (373592021)|DML_BEGIN|[518]|Op:Insert|Type:Account|Rows:1
11:47:40.428 (428649415)|CUMULATIVE_LIMIT_USAGE
11:47:40.428 (428649415)|LIMIT_USAGE_FOR_NS|(default)|
  Number of SOQL queries: 0 out of 100
  Number of query rows: 0 out of 50000
  Number of SOSL queries: 0 out of 20
  Number of DML statements: 0 out of 150
  Number of Publish Immediate DML: 0 out of 150
  Number of DML rows: 0 out of 10000
  Maximum CPU time: 389 out of 10000
  Maximum heap size: 0 out of 6000000
  Number of callouts: 0 out of 100
  Number of Email Invocations: 0 out of 10
  Number of future calls: 0 out of 50
  Number of queueable jobs added to the queue: 0 out of 50
  Number of Mobile Apex push calls: 0 out of 10

11:47:40.428 (428649415)|LIMIT_USAGE_FOR_NS|pba|
  Number of SOQL queries: 3 out of 100
  Number of query rows: 48 out of 50000
  Number of SOSL queries: 0 out of 20
  Number of DML statements: 1 out of 150
  Number of Publish Immediate DML: 0 out of 150
  Number of DML rows: 1 out of 10000
  Maximum CPU time: 0 out of 10000
  Maximum heap size: 0 out of 6000000
  Number of callouts: 0 out of 100
  Number of Email Invocations: 0 out of 10
  Number of future calls: 0 out of 50
  Number of queueable jobs added to the queue: 0 out of 50
  Number of Mobile Apex push calls: 0 out of 10

11:47:40.428 (428649415)|CUMULATIVE_LIMIT_USAGE_END

11:47:40.474 (474108432)|CUMULATIVE_LIMIT_USAGE
11:47:40.474 (474108432)|LIMIT_USAGE_FOR_NS|(default)|
  Number of SOQL queries: 0 out of 100
  Number of query rows: 0 out of 50000
  Number of SOSL queries: 0 out of 20
  Number of DML statements: 0 out of 150
  Number of Publish Immediate DML: 0 out of 150
  Number of DML rows: 0 out of 10000
  Maximum CPU time: 389 out of 10000
  Maximum heap size: 0 out of 6000000
  Number of callouts: 0 out of 100
  Number of Email Invocations: 0 out of 10
  Number of future calls: 0 out of 50
  Number of queueable jobs added to the queue: 0 out of 50
  Number of Mobile Apex push calls: 0 out of 10

11:47:40.474 (474108432)|LIMIT_USAGE_FOR_NS|pba|
  Number of SOQL queries: 3 out of 100
  Number of query rows: 48 out of 50000
  Number of SOSL queries: 0 out of 20
  Number of DML statements: 1 out of 150
  Number of Publish Immediate DML: 0 out of 150
  Number of DML rows: 1 out of 10000
  Maximum CPU time: 0 out of 10000
  Maximum heap size: 0 out of 6000000
  Number of callouts: 0 out of 100
  Number of Email Invocations: 0 out of 10
  Number of future calls: 0 out of 50
  Number of queueable jobs added to the queue: 0 out of 50
  Number of Mobile Apex push calls: 0 out of 10

11:47:40.474 (474108432)|LIMIT_USAGE_FOR_NS|pi|
  Number of SOQL queries: 0 out of 100
  Number of query rows: 0 out of 50000
  Number of SOSL queries: 0 out of 20
  Number of DML statements: 0 out of 150
  Number of Publish Immediate DML: 0 out of 150
  Number of DML rows: 0 out of 10000
  Maximum CPU time: 0 out of 10000
  Maximum heap size: 0 out of 6000000
  Number of callouts: 0 out of 100
  Number of Email Invocations: 0 out of 10
  Number of future calls: 0 out of 50
  Number of queueable jobs added to the queue: 0 out of 50
  Number of Mobile Apex push calls: 0 out of 10

11:47:40.474 (474108432)|CUMULATIVE_LIMIT_USAGE_END

11:47:40.536 (536927578)|CUMULATIVE_LIMIT_USAGE
11:47:40.536 (536927578)|LIMIT_USAGE_FOR_NS|(default)|
  Number of SOQL queries: 0 out of 100
  Number of query rows: 0 out of 50000
  Number of SOSL queries: 0 out of 20
  Number of DML statements: 0 out of 150
  Number of Publish Immediate DML: 0 out of 150
  Number of DML rows: 0 out of 10000
  Maximum CPU time: 452 out of 10000
  Maximum heap size: 0 out of 6000000
  Number of callouts: 0 out of 100
  Number of Email Invocations: 0 out of 10
  Number of future calls: 0 out of 50
  Number of queueable jobs added to the queue: 0 out of 50
  Number of Mobile Apex push calls: 0 out of 10

11:47:40.536 (536927578)|LIMIT_USAGE_FOR_NS|pba|
  Number of SOQL queries: 3 out of 100
  Number of query rows: 48 out of 50000
  Number of SOSL queries: 0 out of 20
  Number of DML statements: 1 out of 150
  Number of Publish Immediate DML: 0 out of 150
  Number of DML rows: 1 out of 10000
  Maximum CPU time: 0 out of 10000
  Maximum heap size: 0 out of 6000000
  Number of callouts: 0 out of 100
  Number of Email Invocations: 0 out of 10
  Number of future calls: 0 out of 50
  Number of queueable jobs added to the queue: 0 out of 50
  Number of Mobile Apex push calls: 0 out of 10

11:47:40.536 (536927578)|LIMIT_USAGE_FOR_NS|pi|
  Number of SOQL queries: 0 out of 100
  Number of query rows: 0 out of 50000
  Number of SOSL queries: 0 out of 20
  Number of DML statements: 0 out of 150
  Number of Publish Immediate DML: 0 out of 150
  Number of DML rows: 0 out of 10000
  Maximum CPU time: 0 out of 10000
  Maximum heap size: 0 out of 6000000
  Number of callouts: 0 out of 100
  Number of Email Invocations: 0 out of 10
  Number of future calls: 0 out of 50
  Number of queueable jobs added to the queue: 0 out of 50
  Number of Mobile Apex push calls: 0 out of 10

11:47:40.536 (536927578)|CUMULATIVE_LIMIT_USAGE_END

11:47:40.561 (561405350)|CUMULATIVE_LIMIT_USAGE
11:47:40.561 (561405350)|LIMIT_USAGE_FOR_NS|(default)|
  Number of SOQL queries: 0 out of 100
  Number of query rows: 0 out of 50000
  Number of SOSL queries: 0 out of 20
  Number of DML statements: 0 out of 150
  Number of Publish Immediate DML: 0 out of 150
  Number of DML rows: 0 out of 10000
  Maximum CPU time: 452 out of 10000
  Maximum heap size: 0 out of 6000000
  Number of callouts: 0 out of 100
  Number of Email Invocations: 0 out of 10
  Number of future calls: 0 out of 50
  Number of queueable jobs added to the queue: 0 out of 50
  Number of Mobile Apex push calls: 0 out of 10

11:47:40.561 (561405350)|LIMIT_USAGE_FOR_NS|pba|
  Number of SOQL queries: 3 out of 100
  Number of query rows: 48 out of 50000
  Number of SOSL queries: 0 out of 20
  Number of DML statements: 1 out of 150
  Number of Publish Immediate DML: 0 out of 150
  Number of DML rows: 1 out of 10000
  Maximum CPU time: 0 out of 10000
  Maximum heap size: 0 out of 6000000
  Number of callouts: 0 out of 100
  Number of Email Invocations: 0 out of 10
  Number of future calls: 0 out of 50
  Number of queueable jobs added to the queue: 0 out of 50
  Number of Mobile Apex push calls: 0 out of 10

11:47:40.561 (561405350)|LIMIT_USAGE_FOR_NS|pi|
  Number of SOQL queries: 0 out of 100
  Number of query rows: 0 out of 50000
  Number of SOSL queries: 0 out of 20
  Number of DML statements: 0 out of 150
  Number of Publish Immediate DML: 0 out of 150
  Number of DML rows: 0 out of 10000
  Maximum CPU time: 0 out of 10000
  Maximum heap size: 0 out of 6000000
  Number of callouts: 0 out of 100
  Number of Email Invocations: 0 out of 10
  Number of future calls: 0 out of 50
  Number of queueable jobs added to the queue: 0 out of 50
  Number of Mobile Apex push calls: 0 out of 10

11:47:40.561 (561405350)|CUMULATIVE_LIMIT_USAGE_END

11:47:40.8 (565112074)|DML_END|[518]
11:47:40.570 (570970643)|CUMULATIVE_LIMIT_USAGE
11:47:40.570 (570970643)|LIMIT_USAGE_FOR_NS|(default)|
  Number of SOQL queries: 0 out of 100
  Number of query rows: 0 out of 50000
  Number of SOSL queries: 0 out of 20
  Number of DML statements: 0 out of 150
  Number of Publish Immediate DML: 0 out of 150
  Number of DML rows: 0 out of 10000
  Maximum CPU time: 482 out of 10000
  Maximum heap size: 0 out of 6000000
  Number of callouts: 0 out of 100
  Number of Email Invocations: 0 out of 10
  Number of future calls: 0 out of 50
  Number of queueable jobs added to the queue: 0 out of 50
  Number of Mobile Apex push calls: 0 out of 10

11:47:40.570 (570970643)|LIMIT_USAGE_FOR_NS|pba|
  Number of SOQL queries: 3 out of 100
  Number of query rows: 48 out of 50000
  Number of SOSL queries: 0 out of 20
  Number of DML statements: 1 out of 150
  Number of Publish Immediate DML: 0 out of 150
  Number of DML rows: 1 out of 10000
  Maximum CPU time: 0 out of 10000
  Maximum heap size: 0 out of 6000000
  Number of callouts: 0 out of 100
  Number of Email Invocations: 0 out of 10
  Number of future calls: 0 out of 50
  Number of queueable jobs added to the queue: 0 out of 50
  Number of Mobile Apex push calls: 0 out of 10

11:47:40.570 (570970643)|LIMIT_USAGE_FOR_NS|pi|
  Number of SOQL queries: 0 out of 100
  Number of query rows: 0 out of 50000
  Number of SOSL queries: 0 out of 20
  Number of DML statements: 0 out of 150
  Number of Publish Immediate DML: 0 out of 150
  Number of DML rows: 0 out of 10000
  Maximum CPU time: 0 out of 10000
  Maximum heap size: 0 out of 6000000
  Number of callouts: 0 out of 100
  Number of Email Invocations: 0 out of 10
  Number of future calls: 0 out of 50
  Number of queueable jobs added to the queue: 0 out of 50
  Number of Mobile Apex push calls: 0 out of 10

11:47:40.570 (570970643)|CUMULATIVE_LIMIT_USAGE_END

11:47:40.575 (575790214)|CUMULATIVE_LIMIT_USAGE
11:47:40.575 (575790214)|LIMIT_USAGE_FOR_NS|(default)|
  Number of SOQL queries: 0 out of 100
  Number of query rows: 0 out of 50000
  Number of SOSL queries: 0 out of 20
  Number of DML statements: 0 out of 150
  Number of Publish Immediate DML: 0 out of 150
  Number of DML rows: 0 out of 10000
  Maximum CPU time: 482 out of 10000
  Maximum heap size: 0 out of 6000000
  Number of callouts: 0 out of 100
  Number of Email Invocations: 0 out of 10
  Number of future calls: 0 out of 50
  Number of queueable jobs added to the queue: 0 out of 50
  Number of Mobile Apex push calls: 0 out of 10

11:47:40.575 (575790214)|LIMIT_USAGE_FOR_NS|pba|
  Number of SOQL queries: 3 out of 100
  Number of query rows: 48 out of 50000
  Number of SOSL queries: 0 out of 20
  Number of DML statements: 1 out of 150
  Number of Publish Immediate DML: 0 out of 150
  Number of DML rows: 1 out of 10000
  Maximum CPU time: 0 out of 10000
  Maximum heap size: 0 out of 6000000
  Number of callouts: 0 out of 100
  Number of Email Invocations: 0 out of 10
  Number of future calls: 0 out of 50
  Number of queueable jobs added to the queue: 0 out of 50
  Number of Mobile Apex push calls: 0 out of 10

11:47:40.575 (575790214)|LIMIT_USAGE_FOR_NS|pi|
  Number of SOQL queries: 0 out of 100
  Number of query rows: 0 out of 50000
  Number of SOSL queries: 0 out of 20
  Number of DML statements: 0 out of 150
  Number of Publish Immediate DML: 0 out of 150
  Number of DML rows: 0 out of 10000
  Maximum CPU time: 0 out of 10000
  Maximum heap size: 0 out of 6000000
  Number of callouts: 0 out of 100
  Number of Email Invocations: 0 out of 10
  Number of future calls: 0 out of 50
  Number of queueable jobs added to the queue: 0 out of 50
  Number of Mobile Apex push calls: 0 out of 10

11:47:40.575 (575790214)|CUMULATIVE_LIMIT_USAGE_END

11:47:40.578 (578866098)|CODE_UNIT_STARTED|[EXTERNAL]|01qb0000000AQUu|ContactTrigger on Contact trigger event BeforeInsert|__sfdc_trigger/ContactTrigger
11:47:40.578 (579583446)|SYSTEM_MODE_ENTER|false
11:47:40.578 (579666624)|SYSTEM_MODE_EXIT|false
11:47:40.578 (579750237)|SYSTEM_MODE_ENTER|false
11:47:40.578 (579794009)|SYSTEM_MODE_EXIT|false
11:47:40.578 (579834195)|SYSTEM_MODE_ENTER|false
11:47:40.578 (580426611)|SYSTEM_MODE_EXIT|false
11:47:40.578 (580475275)|SYSTEM_MODE_ENTER|false
11:47:40.578 (617803488)|SYSTEM_MODE_ENTER|true

11:47:40.578 (720849146)|SYSTEM_MODE_ENTER|true
11:47:40.578 (721212749)|SYSTEM_MODE_EXIT|false
11:47:40.578 (721256256)|SYSTEM_MODE_ENTER|false
11:47:40.578 (722416498)|SOQL_EXECUTE_BEGIN|[180]|Aggregations:0|SELECT Id, Name, Email, Alt_Email__c, Work_Email__c, Phone, HomePhone, MobilePhone, Partner_Phone__c, Partner_Mobile__c, Partner_Email__c, Partner_Work_Email__c FROM Contact WHERE Id NOT IN :triggerItems AND (Email IN :existingInfo OR Alt_Email__c IN :existingInfo OR Work_Email__c IN :existingInfo OR Phone IN :existingInfo OR HomePhone IN :existingInfo OR MobilePhone IN :existingInfo OR Partner_Phone__c IN :existingInfo OR Partner_Mobile__c IN :existingInfo OR Partner_Email__c IN :existingInfo OR Partner_Work_Email__c IN :existingInfo)
11:47:40.578 (736184847)|SOQL_EXECUTE_END|[180]|Rows:1
11:47:40.578 (737185830)|SYSTEM_MODE_EXIT|false
11:47:40.737 (737222689)|CUMULATIVE_LIMIT_USAGE
11:47:40.737 (737222689)|LIMIT_USAGE_FOR_NS|(default)|
  Number of SOQL queries: 1 out of 100
  Number of query rows: 1 out of 50000
  Number of SOSL queries: 0 out of 20
  Number of DML statements: 0 out of 150
  Number of Publish Immediate DML: 0 out of 150
  Number of DML rows: 0 out of 10000
  Maximum CPU time: 482 out of 10000
  Maximum heap size: 0 out of 6000000
  Number of callouts: 0 out of 100
  Number of Email Invocations: 0 out of 10
  Number of future calls: 0 out of 50
  Number of queueable jobs added to the queue: 0 out of 50
  Number of Mobile Apex push calls: 0 out of 10

11:47:40.737 (737222689)|LIMIT_USAGE_FOR_NS|pba|
  Number of SOQL queries: 3 out of 100
  Number of query rows: 48 out of 50000
  Number of SOSL queries: 0 out of 20
  Number of DML statements: 1 out of 150
  Number of Publish Immediate DML: 0 out of 150
  Number of DML rows: 1 out of 10000
  Maximum CPU time: 0 out of 10000
  Maximum heap size: 0 out of 6000000
  Number of callouts: 0 out of 100
  Number of Email Invocations: 0 out of 10
  Number of future calls: 0 out of 50
  Number of queueable jobs added to the queue: 0 out of 50
  Number of Mobile Apex push calls: 0 out of 10

11:47:40.737 (737222689)|LIMIT_USAGE_FOR_NS|pi|
  Number of SOQL queries: 0 out of 100
  Number of query rows: 0 out of 50000
  Number of SOSL queries: 0 out of 20
  Number of DML statements: 0 out of 150
  Number of Publish Immediate DML: 0 out of 150
  Number of DML rows: 0 out of 10000
  Maximum CPU time: 0 out of 10000
  Maximum heap size: 0 out of 6000000
  Number of callouts: 0 out of 100
  Number of Email Invocations: 0 out of 10
  Number of future calls: 0 out of 50
  Number of queueable jobs added to the queue: 0 out of 50
  Number of Mobile Apex push calls: 0 out of 10

11:47:40.737 (737222689)|TOTAL_EMAIL_RECIPIENTS_QUEUED|0
11:47:40.737 (737222689)|STATIC_VARIABLE_LIST|
  int:BYTES:0
  int:BYTES:0
  byte[]:DigitOnes:0
  byte[]:DigitTens:0
  Boolean:FALSE:0
  int:MAX_EXPONENT:0
  double:MAX_VALUE:0
  int:MAX_VALUE:0
  int:MIN_EXPONENT:0
  double:MIN_NORMAL:0
  double:MIN_VALUE:0
  int:MIN_VALUE:0
  double:NEGATIVE_INFINITY:0
  double:NaN:0
  double:POSITIVE_INFINITY:0
  int:SIZE:0
  int:SIZE:0
  Boolean:TRUE:0
  String:__sfdcInnerTypes:0
  String:__sfdcInnerTypes:0
  String:__sfdcInnerTypes:0
  String:__sfdcInnerTypes:0
  String:__sfdcInnerTypes:0
  String:__sfdcInnerTypes:0
  String:__sfdcInnerTypes:0
  String:__sfdcInnerTypes:0
  String:__sfdcInnerTypes:0
  String:__sfdcInnerTypes:0
  String:__sfdcInnerTypes:0
  String:__sfdcInnerTypes:0
  String:__sfdcInnerTypes:0
  String:__sfdcProperties:0
  String:_sfdcAdditionalCodeLocations:0
  String:_sfdcAdditionalCodeLocations:0
  String:_sfdcAdditionalCodeLocations:0
  String:_sfdcAdditionalCodeLocations:0
  String:_sfdcAdditionalCodeLocations:0
  String:_sfdcAdditionalCodeLocations:0
  String:_sfdcAdditionalCodeLocations:0
  String:_sfdcAdditionalCodeLocations:0
  String:_sfdcAdditionalCodeLocations:0
  String:_sfdcAdditionalCodeLocations:0
  String:_sfdcAdditionalCodeLocations:0
  String:_sfdcAdditionalCodeLocations:0
  String:_sfdcAdditionalCodeLocations:0
  String:_sfdcAdditionalCodeLocations:0
  String:_sfdcAdditionalCodeLocations:0
  String:_sfdcAdditionalCodeLocations:0
  String:_sfdcAdditionalCodeLocations:0
  String:_sfdcAdditionalCodeLocations:0
  String:_sfdcAdditionalCodeLocations:0
  String:_sfdcAdditionalCodeLocations:0
  String:_sfdcAdditionalCodeLocations:0
  String:_sfdcAdditionalCodeLocations:0
  String:_sfdcAdditionalCodeLocations:0
  String:_sfdcAdditionalCodeLocations:0
  String:_sfdcAdditionalCodeLocations:0
  String:_sfdcAdditionalCodeLocations:0
  String:_sfdcAdditionalCodeLocations:0
  String:_sfdcAdditionalCodeLocations:0
  String:_sfdcAdditionalCodeLocations:0
  String:_sfdcAdditionalCodeLocations:0
  String:_sfdcAdditionalCodeLocations:0
  String:_sfdcAdditionalCodeLocations:0
  String:_sfdcAdditionalCodeLocations:0
  String:_sfdcAdditionalCodeLocations:0
  String:_sfdcAdditionalCodeLocations:0
  String:_sfdcAdditionalCodeLocations:0
  String:_sfdcAdditionalCodeLocations:0
  String:_sfdcAdditionalCodeLocations:0
  String:_sfdcAdditionalCodeLocations:0
  String:_sfdcAdditionalCodeLocations:0
  String:_sfdcAdditionalCodeLocations:0
  String:_sfdcAdditionalCodeLocations:0
  String:_sfdcAdditionalCodeLocations:0
  String:_sfdcAdditionalCodeLocations:0
  String:_sfdcAdditionalCodeLocations:0
  String:_sfdcAdditionalCodeLocations:0
  String:_sfdcAdditionalCodeLocations:0
  String:_sfdcAdditionalCodeLocations:0
  String:_sfdcAdditionalCodeLocations:0
  String:_sfdcAdditionalCodeLocations:0
  String:_sfdcAdditionalCodeLocations:0
  String:_sfdcAdditionalCodeLocations:0
  String:_sfdcAdditionalCodeLocations:0
  String:_sfdcAdditionalCodeLocations:0
  String:_sfdcAdditionalCodeLocations:0
  String:_sfdcAdditionalCodeLocations:0
  String:_sfdcSuppressedCodeLocations:0
  String:_sfdcSuppressedCodeLocations:0
  String:_static_ACCOUNT_DEFAULT_NAME:0
  Integer:_static_BULK_TRIGGER_THRESHOLD:0
  RecordType:_static_COMPANY_ACCOUNT_DEFAULT:0
  RecordType:_static_COMPANY_CONTACT_DEFAULT:0
  Integer:_static_CONTACT_TYPE:0
  Integer:_static_CONTACT_TYPE:0
  Integer:_static_CPU_TIME_NEEDED:0
  Set<String>:_static_DATETIME_LITERALS:0
  Integer:_static_DELETE_ACTION:0
  Integer:_static_DELETE_ACTION:0
  String:_static_DEPRECIATION:0
  Integer:_static_DML_STATEMENTS_NEEDED:0
  Integer:_static_DML_STATEMENTS_NEEDED:0
  String:_static_EMAIL_CAMPAIGN_BOUNCE:0
  String:_static_EMAIL_CAMPAIGN_CLICK:0
  String:_static_EMAIL_CAMPAIGN_OPEN:0
  String:_static_EMAIL_CAMPAIGN_UNSUBSCRIBE:0
  String:_static_EVENT_NEW:0
  String:_static_EVENT_NEW_TYPE_SHOWING:0
  String:_static_FAVORITE_NEW:0
  RecordType:_static_INDIVIDUAL_ACCOUNT_DEFAULT:0
  RecordType:_static_INDIVIDUAL_CONTACT_DEFAULT:0
  List<RecordType>:_static_INDIVIDUAL_CONTACT_RECORD_TYPES:0
  String:_static_INITIAL_SCORE:0
  Integer:_static_INSERT_ACTION:0
  Integer:_static_LEAD_TYPE:0
  Boolean:_static_LOGGING_DISABLED:0
  Integer:_static_MAX_COLLECTION_SIZE:0
  Integer:_static_MAX_ELEM_LENGTH:0
  String:_static_MAX_FIELD_SUFFIX:0
  Integer:_static_MAX_LENGTH:0
  Integer:_static_MAX_LOOP_ITERATIONS:0
  String:_static_MIN_FIELD_SUFFIX:0
  Integer:_static_QUERIES_NEEDED:0
  Integer:_static_QUERIES_NEEDED:0
  String:_static_REQUEST_NEW:0
  Boolean:_static_SCRAP_LOGS_ON_SUCCESS:0
  String:_static_TASK_COMPLETED_TYPE_CALL:0
  String:_static_TASK_COMPLETED_TYPE_EMAIL:0
  String:_static_TASK_COMPLETED_TYPE_TASK:0
  Integer:_static_TRIGGER_RECORD_SIZE_MAX:0
  Integer:_static_TRIGGER_RECORD_SIZE_MAX:0
  Integer:_static_UNDELETE_ACTION:0
  Integer:_static_UPDATE_ACTION:0
  Boolean:_static_VERBOSE_LOGGING_ENABLED:0
  String:_static_WEBSITE_LISTING_CONTACT_FORM_NEW:0
  String:_static_WEBSITE_LISTING_EMAIL_TO_FRIEND_NEW:0
  String:_static_WEBSITE_LISTING_FAVORITE_NEW:0
  String:_static_WEBSITE_LISTING_INQUIRY_NEW:0
  String:_static_WEBSITE_LISTING_NOTE_NEW:0
  String:_static_WEBSITE_LISTING_SHOWING_NEW:0
  String:_static_WEBSITE_LISTING_VIEW_NEW:0
  Set<Id>:_static_alreadyQueued:0
  Boolean:_static_alreadyThrownNearLimitException:0
  Boolean:_static_arePrivateContactsEnabled:0
  Boolean:_static_bypassAsyncOCLInsertingForUnitTest:0
  Boolean:_static_bypassBatchSchedulerForUnitTest:0
  Map<Schema.SObjectType,Map<String,RecordType>>:_static_cachedRecordTypesByDevName:0
  Map<String,ANY>:_static_config:0
  Boolean:_static_contactAutoRelatePartner:0
  Map<String,Integer>:_static_defaultConfig:0
  Boolean:_static_enabled:0
  String:_static_integrationConfig:0
  Boolean:_static_isAfter:0
  Boolean:_static_isApi:0
  Boolean:_static_isExternalDelete:0
  Boolean:_static_isExternalUpdate:0
  Boolean:_static_isOwnerUpdateEnabled:0
  String:_static_leadScoringConfig:0
  Boolean:_static_leadScoringEnabled:0
  Integer:_static_level:0
  Boolean:_static_ownerUpdateEnabledForTesting:0
  Integer:_static_pbHeapLimit:0
  Integer:_static_pbQueryLimit:0
  Integer:_static_pbRowsLimit:0
  Decimal:_static_percentOfSalesforceLimit:0
  Boolean:_static_performedAsynchronously:0
  Map<String,String>:_static_settings:0
  Boolean:_static_skipForTesting:0
  char[]:digits:0
  long:serialVersionUID:0
  long:serialVersionUID:0
  long:serialVersionUID:0
  int[]:sizeTable:0

11:47:40.737 (737222689)|CUMULATIVE_LIMIT_USAGE_END
```

[image: api log]

Comment: Have you changed password of integration user or that user is not trying to login. Similar stuff happened to us when we found 40-50K requests hit to our org without any actual reasons. Then we found out, middleware keepon trying to login to gain session access(and for login attempt it was using REST api way).

Comment: Hi, I thought this also, but if that was the case it would be a failed login that wouldn't count towards API usage right?

If the login wasn't working we wouldn't be having this issue.

Comment: no, it'd get count. Because when we updated Middleware with proper password/details these request count get stop.

Comment: Try checking your integration teams and updating login details. If it works well and good, if not you'll know with guarantee that other things are causing this issue.

Comment: We have checked and the logins are absolutely correct, and we can see that because it is processing a query.

Comment: How is this integration triggered? Could you have multiple environments pointing to the same Salesforce instance by any chance?